# Unity 3D How to move a object on its X axis so that is parallel to a destined object

Tags: unity-game-engine, math, position

tldr: need help moving an object along x-axis so that it aligns correctly with another object that is z position wise very far away.

Hey, been working on this for a bit of time, and in all honestly vector math is my weakest strength when it comes to unity programming. Really basic stuff I have no propblems but when we start getting into more complicated procedures such as figuring out how to move a object that is not directly walking towards it I have some issues.

Current problem:

I am currently working on my own game, the requirements are that there are three enemies who are all in a single line. When we get to players turn in combat, a 3d-revolver will appear with iron sights pointed at one of the three enemies that the player had chosen earlier. The iron sights are drawn using a screen space-Camera render mode, so a UI camera draws the revolver, the revolver is also aimed at screen as if the player themselves are staring down the iron sights. My issue currently is that I am having trouble moving the revolver to the correct X-axis position so that the gun aligns correctly on top of the enemies unit.

here is a image of my current scene to better understand my issue:

[image of revolver ontop of enemies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rb42A.png)

here is my code, keep in mind I have tried alot of different solutions, this is just my most current attempt so sorry if it seems a bit crazy.

```
Vector3 screenPoint = 
Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(unitBeingAttacked.transform.localPosition);

Vector3 revPoint = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(revolverModel.transform.localPosition);

float posX = screenPoint.x - revPoint.x; 
float posy = screenPoint.y - revPoint.y; 
float posz = screenPoint.z - revPoint.z; 

Vector3 curScreenPoint = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(posX, posy,posz));

revolverModel.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(curScreenPoint.x, 
revolverModel.transform.localPosition.y, revolverModel.transform.localPosition.z);`
```

Answer (score 0):

I will use `transform.position` instead of `transform.localPosition`.
Because the localPosition is the Position, relative to the Parents position. But the Function takes a Position relative to the world Origin.

If I understand you correctly `screenPoint` is the current location of the enemy in screen coordinates. While `revPoint` is the same just for the revolver.

Calculating the X in screenCoords for the revolver is pretty straight forward:
It is just your `screenpoint.x`
The tricky part is getting this to 3D World Coordinates, since our x is just in ScreenCoords.

For that use [Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html), given a Vector3 it returns the WorldCoordinate for X and Y and Z away from the Camera.
From the returned Value use the X to reposition your revolver.

```
Vector3 finalPos = Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(screenpoint.x, revPoint.y, revPoint.z));
actualRevolverWorldCoord.position = new Vector3(finalPos.x, actualRevolverCoord.position.y, actualRevolverCoord.position.z);
```